# Passing string which is the name of entity/perisistance class in createcriteria of hibernate

Tags: ajax, database, spring, hibernate

I have to dynamically load tables for which I was passing through controller and when I have to write hibernate peristance logic of suppose createCriteria, I gave:

```
getSession().createCriteria( Class.forName(tableName)).list()
```

where tableName is a string which would contain the name of the class. Even then I was unscessful and getting ClassNotFound Exception. It works for

`getSession().createCriteria(Book.class).list()` which I feel is hardcoding in my case. Please help regarding with which I could dynamically call tables.

Comment: What is the content of tableName. show the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing the exact classname? Like com.myproject.Myclass or you are just writing the table name????
You should use the complete classname to use with Class.forName(..) method.

Comment: Moreover, there is nothing bad in using 'MyClass.class'. I don't think it is considered as hard-coding.

Comment: Can I instantiate an object of the same string if required. I  mean is:: Book b =new Book(); equivalent to Class.forName("Book").newInstance() ? Actually for the same requirement I have to instantiate objects so as to perform CRUD on the table entries